# mail attachment include project directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'd like to add a pdf file a mail.

```
 mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
```

The pdf path : `http://localhost/WEB/Pages/Customer/PDF/test.pdf`

When I run the code, It gives an error : "`URI formats are not supported.`"
But path is correct, so I can open it.

I think expected path like `C:\\test.pdf` etc. But I want to give path from my project inside. How to do this?

Comment: It is looking for a physical path. Are you storing your files in your site directory? If so, look for questions tagged 'c# relative pathing' and use those solutions for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Server.MapPath and pass the path to the directory

```
MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment( Server.MapPath( "Pages/Customer/PDF/test.txt" ) ); //create the attachment
mail.Attachments.Add( attachment ); //add the attachment
```